# Sitecore Commerce 9.1 Installation - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. on GetIdServerToken

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am installing `Sitecore Commerce 9.1`. While installation I am getting below issue:

```
**[------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GetIdServerToken : GetIdServerToken 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Get Token From Sitecore.IdentityServer
POST https://sc91.identityserver/connect/token with -1-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:05
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\DND\Mindtree\Sitecore\SXC911\Sitecore.Commerce.2019.04-3.0.163\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.2.0.19\Deploy-Sitecore-Comme
rce.ps1:89 char:2
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Verbose *>&1 | Tee-Object  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:32:25**
```

Please help me here dear friends. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide us the installation script with your parameters? Can you also verify, that in general your identity server is up and running? I had such kind of issues when dotnet core was not correctly installed

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to Identity server - `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`
2. Add the **HTTPS** binding for the **storefront/xp** website like :

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [blog article](https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/04/18/sitecore-commerce-9-1-initial-release-step-by-step-install-guide-on-your-machine/) if it helps. Viet has noted down all the errors as well that he faced. Also, the error that you are facing is a part of the comments.

Quoting the solution from the blog:

> You should ensure that your Sitecore Identity Server is up and
> running. If NO, perhaps you installed .Net Core incorrectly (have a
> look at Identity Server’s log and Event Viewer of Windows)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I restarted the identity website and app pool... reset iis... then, resumed installation from the failed task - https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2020/05/getidservertoken-invoke-restmethod.html... Thanks

Comment: Was the error you had the same as what was reported? If so, you could confirm that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check if admin user and password set in installation script is correct. I received this error due to incorrect credentials of admin user to connect to Sitecore.